# Popular Yiddish name for a baby girl born to an unmarried girl

Tags: names, yiddish

As per the Sefer Bris Avos (8-33), Sefer Ha'bris  (page 318-22) and [Zocher Ha'bris  (24-17)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8128&st=&pgnum=168) the name Zindel/Zundel or Isser/Issur was used to name a boy born to an unmarried girl. What was the common name used for a girl born in such circumstances?

Comment: Can you please link the Sefarim you are quoting?

Comment: Who says there was one? Why not ask whether there was one rather than presupposing?

Comment: @GershonGold. Sorry - don't have them or a link to them. Saw them at a local beis medrash.